# Jsoup. Print all text nodes in order

Tags: java, jsoup, textnode

I want to parse this with Jsoup (this is a simplification, I would be parsing entire web pages)

```
<html><body><p>A<strong>B</strong>C<strong>D</strong>E</p></body></html>
```

to obtain all text elements in the order they appear, this is:

```
A B C D E
```

I have tried two approaches:

```
Elements elements = doc.children().select("*");
for (Element el : elements)
    System.out.println(el.ownText());
```

which returns:

```
A C E B D
```

This is, the elements between "strong" tags go at the end.

I have also tried a recursive version:

```
myfunction(doc.children());

private void myfunction(Elements elements) {
  for (Element el : elements){
    List<Node> nodos = el.childNodes();       
    for (Node nodo : nodos) {                
      if (nodo instanceof TextNode && !((TextNode) nodo).isBlank()) {
      System.out.println(((TextNode) nodo).text()); 
    }
  }
  myfunction(el.children());
}
```

But the result is the same as before.

How can this be accomplished? I feel I am making difficult something simple ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
private static void myfunction(Node element) {
    for (Node n : element.childNodes()) {
        if (n instanceof TextNode && !((TextNode) n).isBlank()) {
            System.out.println(((TextNode) n).text());
        } else {
            myfunction(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
String html = "<html><body><p>A<strong>B</strong>C<strong>D</strong>E</p></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
myfunction(doc.body());
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

---

Java 15 update to avoid casting `(TextNode) n` (for more details see [JEP 375: Pattern Matching for instanceof (Second Preview)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/375))

```
private static void myfunction(Node element) {
    for (Node n : element.childNodes()) {
        if (n instanceof TextNode tNode && !tNode.isBlank()) {
            System.out.println(tNode.text());
        } else {
            myfunction(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `text()` method will do the trick e.g. below

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html><body><p>A<strong>B</strong>C<strong>D</strong>E</p></body></html>");
            String texts = doc.body().text();
            System.out.println(texts);
   }
```